# TextView renders ugly bullets for <li> tags

Tags: android, html, textview, spanned, bullet-span

We have the next input String:

```
String test = "<li>Some text</li>\n" +
              "<li>Some text</li>\n" +
              "<li>Some text</li>";
```

Then we create spanned via and set it into the TextView:

```
Html.fromHtml(test);
```

As a result, I will get ugly bullets like here
[image]

I have found a not very good workaround to replace "li" blocks with unicode character:

```
String test = test.replaceAll("<li>(.*?)</li>", "<br>\u2022 $1");
```

The result will be as expected:

[image]

Maybe someone find more clear solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set gravity as center_vertical for the textview. Hope this will help you in getting it as expected.

Comment: Nope, this does not work. This is predictable since we are talking only about one character, and not the whole text.